# Reverse proxy a URI to a Vagrant box

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, hosts

I have a Wordpress Vagrant box that I access through the URL localhost:9001 (forwarded port.).

I am currently trying to make it accessible through the URL "molecare.dev".

I have created the line in the hosts file that catches that URL and points it to my localhost (this is working because I can see the nGinx splash page) but I am having trouble catching this URL in the server block and proxy_pass'ing this to the URL(localhost:9001).

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file`server_name molecare.dev;

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.     
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
```

I have written the following code which I think should do it but I don't know where to place it and if it is correct?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name molecare.dev;

    location / {
            proxy_pass localhost:9001;
    }
```

}

Can anyone see if this is correct and if so where I put this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the folder /etc/nginx/sites-available/ create a config file for your site, say 'molecare.dev.conf'.

Modify the block you wrote to the following and put that in the new file and save it:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name molecare.dev;

    location / {
            proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:9001;
            proxy_redirect  off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Then create a symlink:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/molecare.dev.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/molecare.dev.conf
```

Reload the nginx configuration:

```
service nginx reload
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for thankyou! :)

Comment: You're welcome :) . I would just like to point out that the proxy_set_header lines may not be necessary in your case (not sure what wordpress expects). It depends on your endpoint application.